# Android Sqlite sqlite3_bind_parameter_count

Tags: android, sqlite, placeholder

Hi we want to execute statements that contain the standard sqlite named placeholderpatter like "select * from contatct where contactid=@contactid"

Such statements are defined on our server for other applications (iOS, WIndowsPhone etc.)

I found nothing ind the android.database.sqlite namespace that allows such a handling, it is only the placeholder "?" provided- That really sucks, anyone experience with something like that?

We need something like this raw methods in android
sqlite3_bind_parameter_count
sqlite3_bind_parameter_index
sqlite3_bind_parameter_name

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't now whether there is a chance of using names but you could use [compileStatement()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement%28java.lang.String%29) and bind your parameters by its position in the query (e.g. by using named constants).

Comment: compileStatement does not give me the number of parameters in the statement. and i does not know the names of the aprameters at programming time :(

Comment: There would be no need for names but you're right, you can't get the number of parameters with this approach.

Comment: but i have the need for names and sqlite c++ api provides it too, thus why not android aswell?

Comment: I think that this isn't even possible (besides using native code through NDK). Maybe another answer will proof me wrong...

Comment: [Native Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html). You can write code in C instead java.